# Deleting a particular branch of a in bitbucket repo using API (Shell script)

Tags: shell-script, git, api

I want to delete a particular branch in a repo with help of api using shell script

i have gone through official document https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/4.14.4/bitbucket-branch-rest.html which has details of api to delete all the branches of a repo but not specific branch in a repo

Comment: There is an example in the ressources/delete section for branch my-branch.

Comment: @ Pierre-Alain TORET i didnt found anything in  https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/4.14.4/bitbucket-branch-rest.html  , could you please share that link

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got the answer , below is the api

{bitbucket_url}/rest/branch-utils/1.0/projects/{project_name}/repos/{repo_name}/branches -H "content-type: application/json" -d "{"name": "{branch_name}" ,"dryRun": false}"